# Bing Image Search API returns duplicate reults

Tags: api, azure, search, bing, azure-cognitive-services

The [Bing Image Search API](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=XXX&count=150&offset=YYY&size=Medium&imageType=Photo) returns all duplicate results for `offset > 200 or 300`. This costs money as api calls are wasted. It should stop returning results if it doesn't have any more.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if the Bing Image Search API stopped returning results when the `offset` value is greater than the number of results available, but that's not how the API works. If you look at the [Image Search API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760791.aspx), users are expected to check the `totalEstimatedMatches` parameter from the first request and make sure that the `offset` value has an acceptable value before making subsequent requests:

> The offset should be less than (totalEstimatedMatches - count).

So if you perform this check, you can decide when to stop making new requests. If `offset` exceeds the number of results, it looks like the API just returns the last `count` results which would explain the "duplicate results" you're getting.

Comment: KYT, that doesn't seem to be the answer.  First, the totalEstimatedMatches is totally unreliable.  The value can change wildly for each successive page of results.  Secondly, I have seen that even though duplicate results predominate later pages, new results still appear from time to time . For example,  page 10 may have 29 duplicates and one new item, then page 11 may have 25 duplicates and 5 new items.  There appears to be no way to know when you've reached the end of distinct results.

Comment: P.S.  the video and images search results contain a property "nextOffsetAddCount " (v7 changed to "nextOffset" and changed the meaning a bit. )  THe purpose of this field is to eliminate dupes.  However, it doesn't seem to be avaialable for webpage searches.

Comment: @ElroyFlynn The poster of the question was concerned about wasting api calls. The only way to avoid wasting api calls is to check against totalEstimatedMatches and however much it varies, it's still the value one has to use to decide whether or not to make another call. This is the only solution to avoid wasting api calls and comes straight from the documentation. nextOffsetAddCount is used for eliminating duplicates when paging (the case you described, and it does not do this reliably either) but does nothing to prevent wasted api calls when offset exceeds the number of results available.

Comment: The OP didn't mention whether or not he was respecting totalEstimatedMatches.  In any case,   In my experience, duplicates are returned even when offset < totalEstimatedMatches-count, and new values are returned even when offset > totalEstimatedMatches - count.